# Mocking a function inside of a Redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

I am writing tests for my redux actions. In one of my complex actions I have a function, e.g. `aRandomFunction` that I want to mock. How do I add write a test that mocks a function that is used inside of the `fetchAction`? Thanks! You can see the example below.

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

jest.mock('../../api/handleError');
jest.mock('../../api/handleResponse');

let store;

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

beforeEach(() => {
  store = mockStore({});
  fetchMock.restore();
});

const aRandomAction = () => ({
  type: "RANDOM_ACTION",
})

const aRandomFunction = (data, dispatch) => {
  if (data.isTrue) {
    dispatch(aRandomAction);
  }
};

export const fetchAction = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestAction());
    return fetch('sampleApi/foo')
      .then(response => handleResponse(response))
      .then((json) => {
        aRandomFunction(json.data, dispatch);
        dispatch(receiveAction(json.data));
      })
      .catch(error => handleError(error));
  };
};

describe('testing the fetch Action', () => {
  test('testing the fetch action', () => {
    const expectedActions = [
      { type: "REQUEST_ACTION" },
      { type: "RECEIVE_ACTION", data: "payload" },
    ];
    return store.dispatch(fetchAction()).then(() => {
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you give an example of where `aRandomFunction` comes from? Is it imported from another file?

Comment: @fmoliveira, updated with the function inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot mock `aRandomFunction` in this case, because it's not exported. Although this is not explicitly said in [Jest's documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#using-a-mock-function), please note [in the examples](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#using-a-mock-function) that only importable code can be mocked with Jest. You could focus on testing the final outcome of `fetchAction`, and what happens in the middle wouldn't matter. It's completely fine not to test it because it's implementation details, that is, it only defines the means used by `fetchAction` to achieve its goal, which could change over time and break your tests, even if the goal of `fetchAction` keeps being correctly achieved.

But if it's important for you to be able to test `aRandomFunction`, you will have to move it to an external file, and export it from there. After doing that, you'll be able to mock it in the same way that you're mocking other dependencies, such as `handleError` and `handleResponse`. You can even [define a mock implementation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-implementations) if it's necessary for your test case, for example:

random-function.js

```js
const aRandomAction = () => ({
  type: "RANDOM_ACTION",
});

const aRandomFunction = (data, dispatch) => {
  if (data.isTrue) {
    dispatch(aRandomAction());
  }
}

export default aRandomFunction;
```

your-test-case.spec.js (place this along with your test case from the example in the question)

```js
import aRandomFunction from "./random-function";

jest.mock("./random-function");

aRandomFunction.mockImplementation((data, dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: "MOCK_ACTION" );
});
```